# Javascript: Nicest way to catch a for loop over an undefined/null iterator?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement, ecmascript-6

Consider the next example. Is there a **shorter version which does not require this if-statement**?

```
let d = null  
if (d) { 
  for ( const z of d ) { 
   //
  } 
}
```

For example, is something possible like:

```
let d = null  
for ( d && const z of d ) { 
 //
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I prefer your first version with an explicit `if` check, but if you wanted to golf it down a bit, you could use `d || []`, so that if `d` is falsey, no iterations are performed and no errors are thrown, though this creates an unnecessary intermediate array:

```js
const d = null  
for (const z of d || []) { 
  console.log(z);
}


const e = ['foo'];
for (const z of e || []) { 
  console.log(z);
}
```

Comment: "*I prefer your first version with an explicit `if` check*" me too. Sort of. I actually don't like the extra level of indentation introduced. I'd prefer something more like `if (!d) return;` - where you still have the `if` but you don't add another indentation level to the `for`. But that's more of a personal preference.

Comment: I agree that readable code is way preferable over code with one line less.